# Javascript variable linked to previous value

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript here. I am trying to create a variable duplicated from a object property. When I make changes to the new variable, the original variable is also changed. How can I break the link between the two variables?

For instance,

```
var a = {};
a.data = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var b = a.data;
b.splice(0,1);
```

The output looks like the following.

```
> b
> ["b", "c", "d"]
> a.data
> ["b", "c", "d"]
```

What I expect is this.

```
> b
> ["b", "c", "d"]
> a.data
> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to clone an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clone the array :

```
var b = a.data.slice();
```